# Does a password need encoding when client authenticates using OpenPop?

Tags: c#, pop3, openpop

I'm using openpop to connect to gmail pop server.

This is the code (very simple)

```
using (var client = new Pop3Client())
{
    var username = mailProperties.UserId;
    client.Connect(mailProperties.Server, mailProperties.Port, mailProperties.UseSsl);
    client.Authenticate(username, mailProperties.Password);
}
```

Most of the time it works. But if the password contains "./", the authentication fails and I have an Invalid login exception.
Do I have to encode the password or something? I tried Uri.EscapeDataString but the result is the same.

I verified the password and it's the good one ;)

Comment: OMG! I'm so sorry! I didn't activate the pop option for this email.....

Comment: Can anyone post the answer to close the topic? thanks

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question. You can't accept it for another 48 hours though. [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to activate the pop access in my gmail option for this account.

The problem is now solved.